# Create Tree Structure from Table

Tags: vb.net, recursion, tree

Alright, it's been one of those weeks. I just can't figure out the simplest logic patterns and it's doing my head in.

I've got an object, lets call it TreeNode:

### Object:

```vb
Public Class TreeNode
    Public Key As Object
    Public Children As List(Of TreeNode)

    Public Sub AddToNode(parentNode As TreeNode)
        parentNode.Children.Add(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Simple enough - Create an instance of the class with a Key, and if it has children, I can add each child using the `AddToNode` method.

Onto the data I have.

I have a CTE that is being executed that returns a datatable with the levels clearly defined:

### CTE:

```sql
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT Asset, Name, ParentAsset, [level] = 0 FROM database.schema.Asset WHERE Asset = WhateverAsset and (ParentAsset IS NULL)
UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.Asset, t.Name, t.ParentAsset, [level] = CTE.[level] + 1 FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN database.schema.Asset AS t 
    ON t.ParentAsset = CTE.Asset
) 
SELECT Asset, Name, ParentAsset, [level], CONVERT(BIT, 'FALSE') as Added FROM CTE ORDER BY [level]
```

This returns a datatable that looks like so:

### Data:

`2236|PARENT ASSET|NULL|0|0`
`2233|CHILD ASSET ONE|2236|1|0` 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            `2235|CHILD ASSET TWO|2236|1|0`  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           `2234|CHILD OF CHILD ASSET ONE|2235|1|0`

Now I have this as the following code to generate a list of Nodes and all their children as lists of nodes, etc. etc.

### Recursive Function

```vb
Private Sub GetChildren(dt As DataTable)

    For each row in dt.Rows
        If row.Item("Added") = False Then
            dim node as new Node
            node.Key = row.Item("Asset")

            parentAsset = F.GetNumber(row.Item("ParentAsset"))
            dim foundNode = FlattenAndFind(node)
            ....
            If IsNothing(foundNode) Then
               'Add to overall list
            Else
               node.AddToNode(foundNode)
            End If
            dim nextDt as New Datatable
            dim rows = dt.AsEnumerable.Where(function(suppRow) F.GetNumber(suppRow.Item("ParentAsset")) = parentAsset)
            if rows.Any Then 
                dtt = rows.CopyToDataTable()
            End If
            GetChildreen(nextDt)
        Next
End Sub
```

### FlattenAndFilter (thanks to someone on SO for this function):

```vb
Private Function FlattenAndFilter(source As Node) as IEnumerable(Of Node)
    Dim l As New List(Of Node)
    If source.Key = parentAsset Then l.Add(source)
    If l.Count = 1 Then
        Return l.Concat(source.Children.SelectMany(Function(child) FlattenAndFilter(child)))
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

---

What I get back is a list of each of the objects, not in a tree structure. With some modifications, I get down one level, but the child of a child is added as a parent node.

My question is - can anyone see the flawed logic?

I'm sure it's an easy fix, but I just can't grasp it for whatever reason.

Any help is appreciated, please don't hesitate to comment and ask for further clarification.

Comment: Blorgbeard, may I ask how you did the Syntax highlighting? I would have done so, to make it more readable, but not sure how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you just add a comment before each block like `<!-- language: tag-name -->`. Check out [the advanced editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) - you can get to it by clicking the question mark on the top right of the editor, and then clicking "Advanced help".